# Choosing coeffients for quadrature formula with precision of 1

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

If you are given:

$\int_{-1}^{1} f(x) dx \sim af(\frac{1}{3}) + bf(\frac{2}{3})$

how would you go about determining coefficients of a and b that would produce a quadrature formula with precision of 1? I know the definition of quadrature formula but am having trouble determining the strategy to pick this coefficients.

Comment: it has precision 1, meaning it computes exactly integrals of constant and linear functions. If you, for example, impose that the integral of 1 and $x$ must be exact, you find your parameters

Comment: @Exodd that makes sense, but how would you set a solution for that?

Comment: Substitute $f(x)$ with the function $1$ and the function $x$. You'll find two linear equation in $a,b$, that is a linear system.